# provide method for check status code with pass callback function in bash script

Tags: bash

I faced with problem with organization code. I have api which returned jwt `token` with some expire lifetime and several api which protected by jwt `token`, I need call this api's during some time and jwt `token` can be expired, how to protect from this case ? Need develop some approach until `http_code !=401` -> execute curls, else -> `relogin`. How to organization bash script for correct works ? Maybe need move some logic(aobut check status code 401) to method, how to pass callback function with some curl(for some api) to method ?

This what I did, looking at this, you can analyze it and made conclusion how it should works:

```
http_code='401'
successful_status_code='200'
auth='false'

while [ "$auth" != "true" ]
do
    # in that [if] cheking status code if it 401, int case hwen token expired, need to fetch new token, by again execute api/v2/login
    if [ "$http_code" != "$successful_status_code" ]

    then
    # this curl execute api with username and password from file, then 
    #response with `token` saving in `result.json`, from this file 
    #anotther #api will be fetch token for get access to the protected api
      http_code=$(curl --request POST -sL \
       --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/login'\
       --output './result.json' \
       --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -d "@login.json" \
       --write-out "%{http_code}")

    else

      
      auth='true'
      # fetched token which was saved after api/v2/login curl  
      tokenValue=$(jq -r '.token' './result.json')

      echo 'token was' + $tokenValue
      # For get access to  the potected api need to add header 
      # 'Authorization: Bearer some_token', then apireturn some data, 
      #but in case when toke expired need to execute `api/v2/login`
      # this api curl saved response in file, that's it
      http_code=$(curl --request GET -sL \
           --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/grouptree?_format=json'\
           --output './grouptree_result.json' \
           --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$tokenValue")

      echo "$(cat grouptree_result.json)"
    fi

done
```

How I imagine it, some bash script should executed several api during by some time period, so need to provide some structure which should be catch case when toke will be expire and relogin again, saving new tokne in file.

```
#some scenario where several api's should be call

statuscode = executeApi(fetchGroupTree())
statuscode = executeApi(fetchSomeData())
...
//etc methods which call api

#method which provide approach catch 401 and relogin user, refresh 
#toke and then again execute current api method
public function executeApi(function api())
{
   statuscode = execute api()
   if (statuscode == 401) {
       execute auth()
       statuscode = execute api()
   }
   return statuscode
}
# another some api which expect not expire token for provide access
public function fetchSomeData()
{
          tokenValue=$(jq -r '.token' './result.json')
    
          echo 'token was' + $tokenValue

          // execute some curl api
}

# some api which expect not expire token for provide access
public function fetchGroupTree()
{
          tokenValue=$(jq -r '.token' './result.json')
    
          echo 'token was' + $tokenValue
    
          curl --request GET -sL \
               --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/grouptree?_format=json'\
               --output './grouptree_result.json' \
               --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$tokenValue" \
    
          echo "$(cat grouptree_result.json)"
}

# method for relogin and saving new token in file after old token was expired
public function auth()
{
        http_code=$(curl --request POST -sL \
         --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/login'\
         --output './result.json' \
         --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -d "@login.json" \
         --write-out "%{http_code}")
}
```

But this is my vision, I'm not expert on bash scripts how usually develop bash script for this goal, maybe some best practices ?

Comment: could you please share what went wrong? was it perhaps because the *first* curl command does not have this flag? `--header 'Authorization: Bearer'"$(cat grouptree_result.json)"`

Comment: Current script executed correct. First curl did not should has `header 'Authorization: Bearer` becuase this is `api/v2/login` for fetch token, which will be using in next curl request. Problem is structure bash script will be looks better if have method or something for control status code from response

Comment: I updated answer

Comment: `echo "$(cat` is a useless use of echo. Just `cat`. || I must say I do mot understand your `How I imagine it` at all. Where do you loop there? You did just an `if`. Could you write comments to your original code? What does the `curl` do? What do you check there? What is `auth`?

Comment: I updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You typically write some wrappers:

```
# the tokenfile location
tokenf=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$tokenf"' EXIT

# just some abstractions
get_token() {
    cat "$tokenf"
}
has_token() {
    [[ -s "$tokenf" ]]
}
clear_token() {
    : > "$tokenf"
}

# the generic curl wrapper way we take
# remember to add -S so that you see errors
_curl() {
    curl -sSL "$@"
}

# execute authentication request and place the result in token file
do_auth() {
   local cmd
   cmd=(
       _curl --request POST
       --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/login'
       --output "$tokenf"
       --header "Content-Type: application/json"
       -d "@login.json"
       # TODO: implement checking error code
       # --write-out "%{http_code}"
   )
   "${cmd[@]}"
}

# small wrapper so that loop looks nice
# first argument - filename for output
# other arguments passed to curl
# outputs HTTP exit code
_execute_api_callback() {
   local outf cmd
   outf="$1" 
   shift
   cmd=(
      _curl --request GET
      --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$(get_token)" 
      --output "$outf" --write-out "%{http_code}"
      "$@"
   )
   "${cmd[@]}"
}

# run curl request in a loop requesting for authentication
execute_api() { 
   # execute in a subshell for EXIT trap to auto-cleanup
   (  
      # The temporary location for curl output
      tmpf=$(mktemp)
      trap 'rm "$tmpf"' EXIT
      while
         # TODO: check other error codes
         statuscode=$(_execute_api_callback "$tmpf" "$@")  
         ((statuscode != 200)
         # TODO: implement timeout
      do
         do_auth   # TODO: check failure
      done
      cat "$tmpf"
  )
}

if ! has_token; then
   do_auth
fi
# is --url really that needed?
execute_api 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/grouptree?_format=json'
```

This is just a code I have written in 5 mins on this forum - I did not test it, I did not run it. Check your code with https://shellcheck.net , read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 and check out https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters .